# Javascript closure freezing values of incrementer

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I'm having a tough time understanding and using closures (yes, I have read [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top))

My problem is as follows:

```
for (row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
    for (column = 0; column < 10; column++) {

        var target = $("#" + Data.Row[row].Column[column].ID);

        target.mouseenter(function () {
            var position = CalculatePosition($(this));

            alert("row:" + row + ",column:" + column);

            ...
        });
    }
}
```

As you might expect, row and column is always 9 whenever target has the mouse over it. My question is then, how can I freeze the value of row and column so that the mouseevent anonymous function can get their intended values? I tried doing something like

```
target.mouseenter(function() {}.bind(column));
```

And that seems to work for just column, but then of course `this` is no longer referring to target.

Comment: Nah, [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) does something different which you can't use here (also read [about the `this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this))

Comment: @Bergi He can use `bind` like: `function(row, column){}.bind(target, row, column)`.

Comment: I suspect you want the function to know which element was clicked and each element has a different ID. True?

Comment: @Paulpro: Ah, didn't see that he knows `this`/`target[0]` outside of the handler already. Wouldn't have worked for larger collections at least…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest option here is generally to define a function that returns your handler:

```
function getHandler(row, column)
    return function () {
        var position = CalculatePosition($(this));
        alert("row:" + row + ",column:" + column);
        // ...
    };
}
```

Then call this function in your loop to get your handler with the relevant variables "fixed" to their values at call time:

```
for (row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
    for (column = 0; column < 10; column++) {
        var target = $("#" + Data.Row[row].Column[column].ID);
        target.mouseenter(getHandler(row, column));
    }
}
```

You  can also do this within the loop, in an immediately executing anonymous function:

```
for (row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
    for (column = 0; column < 10; column++) {
        var target = $("#" + Data.Row[row].Column[column].ID);
        target.mouseenter((function(row, column) {
            return function () {
                var position = CalculatePosition($(this));

                alert("row:" + row + ",column:" + column);

                ...
            };
        })(row, column)));
    }
}
```

But IMO that's a lot uglier and harder to read.

In either case, the basic approach here is to establish a new function scope, using the loop variables as arguments; now when you use them in the handler callback, they're no longer references to outer-scope variables.

Comment: +1 This works by creating a new closure for each iteration through the loops and that closure contains the mouse enter handler too. That way the handler for each element has its own stored x and y values.

Comment: Thanks! The solution makes a lot more sense in my head now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) like so (the first argument is the context (`this` arg)):

```
target.mouseenter(function(row, column){
    ...
}.bind(target[0], row, column));
```

But bind is not cross browser, and you are already using jQuery, so you should use [proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) instead:

```
target.mouseenter($.proxy(function(row, column){
    ...
}, target[0], row, column));
```

Comment: Yet you should use `target[0]` to get the DOM element only, or remove `$()` from `this` inside the handler.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, I didn't notice that `target` was a jQuery object (I assumed it was `e.target` from some event handler). I've updated it to use `target[0]`.